# UTF-8 to Unicode using C#

Tags: c#, json, unicode, utf-8, encode

Help me please. I have problem with encoding response string after GET request:

```
var m_refWebClient = new WebClient();
var m_refStream = m_refWebClient.OpenRead(this.m_refUri);
var m_refStreamReader = new StreamReader(this.m_refStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var m_refResponse = m_refStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

After calling this code my string m_refResponse is **json source with substrings like `\u041c\u043e\u0439`**. What is it? How to encode it for Cyrillic? I am very tired after a lot of attempts.

**corrected**

Comment: You'll need to give more information - like what encoding you *expect* to get. Is there any reason why you're not just using DownloadString?

Comment: what if you put Cyrillic instead of `Encoding.UTF8` (line 4)? And Unicode?

Comment: @Jon, thank you, i can use DownloadString, but result will be the same)

Comment: @MainMa, i tried a lot of combinations of encoding and i tried Encoding.Convert, but still nothing)))

Comment: If the result of DownloadString is the same, that means the web server isn't giving you the data correctly - it may be screwing up the Content-Type header, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something here?

> What is it?

`"\u041c\u043e\u0439"` is the String literal representation of `Мой`. You don't have to do anything more, Strings are Unicode, you've got your Cyrillic already.

(Unless you mean you *literally* have the sequence `\u041c\u043e\u0439`, ie. the value `"\\u041c\\u043e\\u0439"`. That wouldn't be the result of an encoding error, that would be something happening at the server, for example it returning a JSON string, since JSON and C# use the same `\u` escapes. If that's what's happening use a JSON parser.)

Comment: thanks a lot!!! It was my mistake, that i did not provide full information as @Jon said! my response is json document, but before parsing it with Newton's json library, i watched it in test console)))) I forgot about formating, sorry! now it works nice!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% on this, but I would assume you'd have to pass Encoding.Unicode to StreamReader.

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is actually the UTF-16LE encoding. (Microsoft love to describe UTF-16LE as ‘Unicode’, as that's the encoding Windows uses for string storage internally, but the naming is highly misleading.) It's *extremely* unusual for a web server to return UTF-16-encoded content (being non-ASCII-compatible, it tends to break a lot if they try); UTF-8 is a much more likely possibility.