# Getting text from web request

Tags: c#, json, encoding, cyrillic

Here is my code:

```
            Uri myUri = new Uri("my url");
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (myUri);

            // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
            request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
            request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
            // Set credentials to use for this request.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

            Console.WriteLine ("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
            Console.WriteLine ("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

            // Get the stream associated with the response.
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

            // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
            Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
            response.Close ();
            readStream.Close ();
```

Response should be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "book_name": "CYRILLIC LETTERS",
        "book_id": "Text",
    },
    {
        "book_name": "CYRILLIC LETTERS",
        "book_id": "Text",
    },
]
```

StreamReader.ReadToEnd() is returning everything I want but it is replacing the Cyrillic letters to numbers like: **\u041c\u0410\u0422\u0422\u041e**

What should I do to be able get everything properly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with Unicode?

```
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Or this:

```
System.Text.UnicodeEncoding encodingUNICODE = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] textBytesCyrillic = encodingUNICODE.GetBytes(readStream.ToString());

Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
Console.WriteLine (encodingUNICODE.GetString(textBytesCyrillic));
```

Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812582/4315001) you are already getting the cyrillic value in the form of string. Try the suggestion of the answer if you can display the original form of the cyrillic.

Comment: If I change it to the Encoding to Unicode then everything is question mark.

Comment: Your first example showing everything as question mark and second one showing "System.IO.StreamReader". Have you tried this on your computer?

Comment: my mistake on first, I tried this on my computer, but only used a simple string cyrillic string, and works

Comment: I tried the same thing. I put the text into a txt file and read text using StreamWriter with Encoding.UTF8. It works fine. Only issue when text comes from web request.

Comment: According to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812065/utf-8-to-unicode-using-c-sharp), the result your getting is the string representation of the cyrillic you got from the web request, which means you already have your cyrillic. Try passing it to your view or the suggestion in the link I provided.

Comment: You are right. That was the problem. So, can you post that so that I can mark it as answer?